# Why has the author chosen future in a clause time?

Tags: difference, time, future

> may be I'll get to you some day until then I'll keep on walking through the rain.

> he will play until he arrives

Both are clause time, why has the author chosen future for the verb in the first clause. Normally or most of the time the verb in a clause time is in the present tense like the second example. When the clause time is in future it means that the person is willing to do something.

What is different in these two examples and why?

In the first example he first keeps on walking and at the end of it he will get to the person (the first action is keeping on walking and the second action getting to the person.

In the second example the first action is playing, the second action arriving.

So both examples work the same.

Comment: The first could have been written as "I will keep on walking until I get to you" - except that he is not confident that he will ever 'get to her'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first sentence is actually two sentences, badly punctuated, so let's rewrite them:

> Maybe I'll get to you some day. Until then, I'll keep on walking through the rain.

The time in the first sentence is just "then". "I'll keep walking..." is the main clause of the sentence. It could be rewritten:

> I'll keep on walking through the rain **until then**.